# Color \skippedwords in bytefield package respectively background color in general

Tags: color, bytefield

The manual of the **bytefield** package explains how to color a normal bitfield with a colored `\rule`.  I'm also using the `\skippedwords` command in my figures. I would like to also color that fields. However, it seems that there is no option in the bytefield package for a general color changing. Does somebody has an idea how to accomplish that, a workaround or a package suggestion? I know that I could draw everything with tikz but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Providing a working example would be beneficial for those seeking to offer help.  Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following, I defined a command `\cskippedwords` allowing you to apply a background color using the mandatory argument. The syntax is

```
\cskippedwords[<length>]{<color>}
```

where the optional argument `<length>` has the same meaning that for the standard `\skippedwords`, and color will be applied with a `0.2` opacity.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bytefield}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cskippedwords}[2][2ex]{%
  \setlength{\units@wide}{\bf@bitwidth * \bits@wide}%
  \setlength{\units@high}{1pt * \ratio{\units@wide}{6.0pt}}%
  \setlength{\units@tall}{#1 + \units@high}%
  \edef\num@wide{\strip@pt\units@wide}%
  \edef\num@tall{\strip@pt\units@tall}%
  \edef\num@high{\strip@pt\units@high}%
  \begin{picture}(\num@wide,\num@tall)%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \draw[fill=#2,fill opacity=0.2] 
    (0,-\bf@bitheight) -- (0,0) -- (0,\units@high) -- (\units@wide,0) -- +(0,-\bf@bitheight) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=#2,fill opacity=0.2]
    (0,\units@high+#1+\bf@bitheight) -- ++(\units@wide,0) -- ++(0,-\bf@bitheight-\units@high) -- (0,\units@high+#1) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \end{picture}%
  \ifcounting@words
    \inc@bytefield@height{\unitlength * \real{\num@tall}}%
    \global\counting@wordsfalse
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{bytefield}{16}
\wordbox{1}{Some data} \\
\wordbox[lrt]{1}{Lots of data} \\
\cskippedwords{blue!20} \\
\wordbox[lrb]{1}{} \\
\wordbox{2}{More data}
\end{bytefield}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{bytefield}[bitheight=2.5\baselineskip]{32}
\bitheader{0,7,8,15,16,23,24,31} \\
\begin{rightwordgroup}{\parbox{6em}{\raggedright These words were taken
verbatim from the TCP header definition (RFC~793).}}
\bitbox{4}{Data offset} & \bitbox{6}{Reserved} &
\bitbox{1}{\tiny U\\R\\G} & \bitbox{1}{\tiny A\\C\\K} &
\bitbox{1}{\tiny P\\S\\H} & \bitbox{1}{\tiny R\\S\\T} &
\bitbox{1}{\tiny S\\Y\\N} & \bitbox{1}{\tiny F\\I\\N} &
\bitbox{16}{Window} \\
\bitbox{16}{Checksum} & \bitbox{16}{Urgent pointer}
\end{rightwordgroup} \\
\wordbox[lrt]{1}{Data octets} \\
%\skippedwords \\
\cskippedwords{green} \\
\wordbox[lrb]{1}{} \\
\begin{leftwordgroup}{\parbox{6em}{\raggedright Note that we can display,
for example, a misaligned 64-bit value with clever use of the
optional argument to \texttt{\string\wordbox} and
\texttt{\string\bitbox}.}}
\bitbox{8}{Source} & \bitbox{8}{Destination} &
\bitbox[lrt]{16}{} \\
\wordbox[lr]{1}{Timestamp} \\
\begin{rightwordgroup}{\parbox{6em}{\raggedright Why two Length fields?
No particular reason.}}
\bitbox[lrb]{16}{} & \bitbox{16}{Length}
\end{leftwordgroup} \\
\bitbox{6}{Key} & \bitbox{6}{Value} & \bitbox{4}{Unused} &
\bitbox{16}{Length}
\end{rightwordgroup}
\end{bytefield}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Flasher You're welcome. I updated my answer fixing a little problem with one of the lengths I used; the improved code might be of interest for you.